# Authenticate with Facebook from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Windows service which sits on a database server and its objective is to notify the public when particular fields in the database change.

I would like to be able to post to a corporate Facebook page when a field changes so people who like and follow the page can be notified of progress through the pages statuses.

The issue I have is that with this being a Windows service there is no UI and no URL associated with the service so I am unable to authenticate with Facebook and this stops me posting statuses to the page wall.

Is there a way I can log in with Facebook and post to their API to update my Facebook page without using a redirect URL and without user interaction?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: All you need for the API request to make the posts is the proper access token. Nothing’s stopping you from getting that “outside” of your service and simply copy&pasting it into a configuration file manually, or something like that.

Comment: The issue is that from looking at the Facebook documentation the keys will only last a maximum of 60 days.  I need the service to be able to continuously update the key automatically without user intervention.

Comment: That is for extended user tokens, but since you want to post as the page, that does not even apply. So go read again, what the conditions are for extended page tokens. Any kind of “automatic” refreshing without any user interaction is not possible however. So _if_ your page token gets invalidated, you need to have a mechanism in place to get a new one. And that means, if you don’t want to perform the main parts of this process manually or using Graph API Explorer, you will have to properly implement login somewhere to begin with.